# How to obtain result from a website using Http in android

Tags: android, httpwebrequest

I want to use an external website http://www.siirretytnumerot.fi/ in my android application. This website takes in two values PREFIX and NUMBER. I am confused at the moment as I seem not to be getting any output in my textview. I dont know what to use whether httpget or httppost. I tried both and still no result. But when i go to the link for explorer and enter an input the website line changes to http://www.siirretytnumerot.fi/QueryServlet. I have tried to use both still no output.
Please can someone help me look through the website and suggest which of the http methods is correct for me to use?
here is the code I used.

```
 TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.display);
  try {
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();  
    String postURL = "http://www.siirretytnumerot.fi/";
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(postURL); 
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("PREFIX", "044"));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("NUMBER", "9782231"));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("LANGUAGE", "Finnish"));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Submit", "Hae"));
        UrlEncodedFormEntity ent = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params,HTTP.UTF_8);
        post.setEntity(ent);
        HttpResponse responsePOST = client.execute(post);  
        HttpEntity resEntity = responsePOST.getEntity();  
        if (resEntity != null) {    
            tv.setText(EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
        }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

the output from the link comes out as an image source

```
<img src="QueryServlet?ID=-7187780920186056107&amp;STRING=5WQAy%2BQCUZRGIUJ8qZtpSrmkiKzWp8HRL7Ti1xmFSxMAEZE7GHEtaylOApMGd9qoesY7Pl%2BUN1Z6Kzap9RIg%2Bw==" />
```

Now how do i read this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use developer tools of browser to find out which fields are required.

You should make `POST` request to http://www.siirretytnumerot.fi/QueryServlet

Try to add these fields to your request:

```
Submit: Hae
LANGUAGE: Finnish
```

I hope it'll help

**EDIT**

It will look like that

```
TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.display);
  try {
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();  
    String postURL = "http://www.siirretytnumerot.fi/";
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(postURL); 
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("PREFIX", "044"));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("NUMBER", "9782231"));

        //here the new lines
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("LANGUAGE", "Finnish"));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Submit", "Hae"));

        UrlEncodedFormEntity ent = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params,HTTP.UTF_8);
        post.setEntity(ent);
        HttpResponse responsePOST = client.execute(post);  
        HttpEntity resEntity = responsePOST.getEntity();  
        if (resEntity != null) {    
            tv.setText(EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
        }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: thanks for you response but can you kindly edit the code and add your line to it so I can understand what is it you want me to do.

Comment: I edited the code still no output in my textview. what can be wrong?

Comment: make sure that you didn't get an exception

Comment: No it is working now but the output is in XML form. and the also it is displayed as a image source. Is there anyway that i can decode this? I have edited the code above to include the image source

Comment: What result do expect? Sorry, I don't know finnish and do not understand what this site about )

Comment: Ok sorry. the site is also in english. The result I want is suppose to be a string as displayed on the website but when i check the source code after the search the output is given in an img src like this <img src="QueryServlet?ID=-7187780920186056107&amp;STRING=5WQAy%2BQCUZRGIUJ8qZtpSrmkiKzWp8HRL7Ti1xmFSxMAEZE7GHEtaylOApMGd9qoesY7Pl%2BUN1Z6Kzap9RIg%2Bw==" />. Is there anyway i can get this exact text?

Answer (score 1):

You can view the source and there is a line

```
<input type="hidden" name="LANGUAGE" value="Finnish">
```

So you need to add that field too,as they might be using it.So

```
 params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("LANGUAGE", "Finnish"));
```

Comment: thanks but I have edited the code still no output in my textview. what can be wrong?

Comment: I would probably start out with checking resEntity as text before putting it into textview.Is there any NetworkOnMainThread exception??

Comment: It displayed but what am getting is the source code but when I checked the website after inputing a data the output is in the form of a img src:<img src="QueryServlet?ID=-7187780920186056107&amp;STRING=5WQAy%2BQCUZRGIUJ8qZtpSrmkiKzWp8HRL7Ti1xmFSxMAEZE7GHEtaylOApMGd9qoesY7Pl%2BUN1Z6Kzap9RIg%2Bw==" />